# SQLAlchemy: Using a CTE from a (sub)query w/ FROM clause specified as literal text

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a system where queries and CTEs can be provided by the user as textual configuration. One possible configuration is akin to the following:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
cte = sa.select([sa.sql.text('* from foo')]).cte('foo_cte')
q = sa.select([sa.sql.text('* from (select * from foo_cte)')])
```

As it is, this query will not include the CTE preamble when rendered:

```
>>> print q
SELECT * from (select * from foo_cte)
```

If, however, I add all possible CTEs to the select list:

```
q = q.select_from(cte)
```

...then they have additional and extranous FROM clauses added by SQLAlchemy on render, making the syntax invalid:

```
>>> print q
WITH foo_cte AS
(SELECT * from foo)
 SELECT * from (select * from foo_cte)
FROM foo_cte
```

---

Is it possible to have it both ways -- printing the CTE preamble without also adding it to the generated FROM clause?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you defined `q` as

```
q = sa.select(['*']).select_from(cte)
```

Then sqlalchemy is able to figure out the proper sql to emit:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
cte = sa.select([sa.text('* from foo')]).cte('foo_cte')    
q = sa.select(['*']).select_from(cte)

print(q)
WITH foo_cte AS
(SELECT * FROM foo)
 SELECT *
FROM foo_cte
```

Comment: Thank you! Btw skipping square brackets like `sa.select('*')` seems to work just as fine.